# List All MMM-YYYY Combination for Year

Tags: sql, db2

How do I list out such data in DB2?

```
FiscalMonthYear
----------
Dec-2010
Jan-2011
Feb-2011
..
Nov-2011
```

The very first MM-YYYY combination is always 'Dec' + '-' + CHAR(CURRENT YEAR - 1)

Comment: Are you planning on joining to these results, or is this just for display?

Comment: @X-Zero I'm joining the results

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't recommend joining on a (formatted) text column like this (especially something that is very language-dependant).
Generally, try joining month/years like this:

```
SELECT columnList
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB
ON tableB.numericMonth = MONTH(tableA.date)
AND tableB.numericYear = YEAR(tableA.date)
```

Although it should be noted that it would be preferred to have two date columns to join on, rather than separated columns like this.

Generating the (separated, numeric) range is fairly simple:

```
WITH date_range (month, year) as (SELECT 12, 2011
                                  FROM sysibm/sysdummy1
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT month - 1, 2012
                                  FROM date_range
                                  WHERE month > 1)
```

Although, hopefully you would really be joining (if possible) on an actual date, at which point the statement should look something like this:

```
SELECT columnList
FROM tableA
WHERE tableDate BETWEEN '2011-12-01' and '2012-11-30'
```

There is also a `MONTHNAME()` function in DB2 which will return the (long) name of the month.  Generates these results:

```
December                  
November                  
October                   
September                 
August                    
July                      
June                      
May                       
April                     
March                     
February                  
January
```

... Which you could substring to get the first 3 characters.  Keep in mind that the value returned is *language dependant* (based on the system settings of the running job), so it's a terrible thing to use for a join column (which is why I don't recommend using month-name as a join condition - use month number).

Comment: thanks! For some reason, I keep getting an error when run the WITH date_range .. code. `SQL0104N  An unexpected token ")" was found following "ange WHERE month > 1". Expected tokens may include:  ")".  SQLSTATE=42601` I also changed the sysibm/sysdummy1 to sysibm.sysdummy1

Comment: Don't worry about the `.` vs `/` separators - this is just 'system' versus 'SQL' conventions (I can never remember which is which).  I don't know why you're getting the token error, as I used that exact statement on my (DB2) system with no problems - do you have a UDF for 'date_range' or something?

Comment: No, I don't have a UDF for date_range. Am I supposed to?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, just wondering what's throwing it off about the parenthesis... like maybe it got its token count off somehow... Can you at least do the standard CTE (remove everything from 'UNION ALL' to '> 1') and select from it?  You should only get 1 row.